# How do I reauthenticate my logger after cookie expires

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, axios

When first logging into my web application the logger is authenticated by setting the `withCredentials` parameter for `AxiosRequestConfig` to true. Here is the authentication class the logger uses to do that:

```
export class UserCredentialsAuth implements LogsRestAuthScheme {
    isWithCredentials = true

    public getAuthHeaders(): AxiosHeaders {
        return new AxiosHeaders()
    }
}
```

The logger works as expected for the first 15 minutes, but after that time the cookie expires and is refreshed. The issue is that `withCredentials` does not account for the refreshed cookie and the logger then proceeds to get 401 responses when attempting to post.

I'm not sure how to best go about resolving this. My application uses a node module that handles token refreshing, but I'm not sure how to use that in my logger node module.

Here is how to logger is initialized in my web application:

```
const logger = Logger.init({

    logIndex: "",
    authentication: new UserCredentialsAuth(),
    logDefaults: {
        appInstanceId: "",
        sessionId: sessionId,
        userId: "",
        appVersion: navigator.appVersion.match(/\S*/)![0],
        os: (navigator as any).userAgentData
            ? (navigator as any).userAgentData.platform
            : navigator.userAgent,
        env: env,
    }

})
```

When looking at the network requests, the cookie under the request headers has the name it was set as for the first 15 minutes, but after 15 minutes it changes and it begins with "CONSENTMGR" which may be the cause of the issue.